# How to let only numbers or "n/a" to write to a specific column with data validation?

Tags: excel

I have a column where a user can only write company codes (integers), and in case of no company codes they can write "n/a". Is it possible to do this with data validation? To sum up, they can write only one string ("n/a") or any number.

Answer (score 4):

Use a custom formula:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(A1),A1="n/a")
```

Comment: Thank you, can you please modify this to a form where It is able to validate a whole column? (I dont know how may rows of data will be in that column. Maybe there is something to do with usedrange?)

Comment: You would apply it to the full column but the cell reference would only be the top cell in the applied to column.